# Android Webview Scroll After Color

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I am making an android webview application. However, when the user scrolls off the screen, I want the part I show in the picture not to appear.

How can I do that ? Thank you for your help.

[image]

Comment: check out my question in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57654466/nestedwebview-working-properly-with-scrollingviewbehavior), you will find in there some clues (especially `ScrollingViewBehavior`)

Comment: @snachmsm I don't know much. Is it that hard to destroy it?

Comment: what do you mean by "that hard to destroy it"?

Comment: @snachmsm When you scroll up, down or left and right in the application, things like the balloon in the picture appear.

I don't want them to come off.

Also, how can I disable swiping left and right?

Comment: you are talking about `Toolbar` or this gray curved shape, so-called overscroll effect, which can be disabled easily with line `webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);`?

Comment: @snachmsm Yes. This worked. But can you tell me what exactly it does? Scrolling disabled? (it doesn't look like that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235534/discussion-between-coinanalyzer-and-snachmsm).

Answer (score 2):

for disabling overscroll effect just use

```
webView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```

some doc in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView#setOverScrollMode(int)). this is just some visual effect, which you can have or just disable like you want. it doesn't affecting any scrolling possibility

edit: worth adding that Android 12 changed this behavior, from "glow effect" to ["stretch effect"](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-all#overscroll). still same way for configuring/disabling it as above